# {Something} as expressed by {someone}

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrases

> Confidence and self-respect **as expressed by** members of a group.
>
> Few things are funnier or more shocking than moral indignation **as expressed by** a total bastard.
>
> But he does still have a heart (**as expressed by** his affection for the mysterious Rosebud) if not a soul.

What does "as expressed by" exactly mean?

What is the meaning of "confidence and self respect" in this context?

What does "as" do in this sentence?

Comment: It would help if you confined your question to one part of the sentence, instead of asking about multiple parts.  Also, you need more detail to explain what you think it might mean, and why it is confusing to you.

Comment: isn't it clear? i don't know "As expressed by" completely

Comment: The first sentence is only a sentence fragment; it's not a complete sentence. (It's a noun phrase without a verb.)